# Dropdown selection value in many textbox from Database using ASP.NET MVC 5 using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have problem to see many texbox from dropdownlist at initial load, it only load one textbox but the other not worked, that dropdown populated by database  change I use ajax and jQuery and ASP.NET MVC 5.

well here's the code dropdown

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Rang, ViewBag.listRangs as SelectList, "إختر الرتبة", htmlAttributes : new { @class = "form-control", @id = "drop", onchange = "getValue()" })
```

and the textbox

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cours, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "cour" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tds, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tds, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "td" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tds, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tps, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tps, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "tp" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tps, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and function onchange

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Coordonnees/GetData",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                var s = '<option value="-1">إختر الرتبة</>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    s += '<option value="' + data[i].Cour + '">' + data[i].Nom + '</option>';
                    s += '<option value="' + data[i].td + '">' + data[i].Nom + '</option>';
                    s += '<option value="' + data[i].tp + '">' + data[i].Nom + '</option>';
                }
                $("#drop").html(s);
            }
        });
    });
    function getValue() {
        var cVal = $("#drop").val();
        $("#cour").val(cVal);
    }
    function getValue() {
        var dVal = $("#drop").val();
        $("#td").val(dVal);
    }
    function getValue() {
        var pVal = $("#drop").val();
        $("#tp").val(pVal);
    }
```

Controller action method:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var data = from als in db.Ranglists select new { als.Nom, als.Cour, als.td, als.tp };
    return Json(data.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Really not clear what the specific problem is here

Comment: i have three value in the dropdown i was load in three textbox the problem is if i run the project watch the three value in one textbox input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined 3 same name `getValue()` functions..., so `onchange` will call the last one by **hoisting**.

Integrate them to only one:

```js
function getValue() {
    var cVal = $("#drop").val();
    $("#cour").val(cVal);
    $("#td").val(cVal);
    $("#tp").val(cVal);
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer but in textbox appear the same value . 
I want each value to appear in a textbox for example the value of "cour" appears in the textbox id "cour" and the value of "td" appears in the textbox id "td" and the value of "tp" appears in the textbox id "tp"